# Unlocking Xperia x10 using a jacket

Tags: sony-ericsson-xperia-x10, sim-unlocking

I have passed the limits for attempting passcode / sim code. Someone has advised me that I should use a jacket to unlock the phone (Xperia X10a)

Where do I get the jacket from? Also, will the jacket solve my problem?

Comment: When you say "a jacket", do you mean "a JTAG cable"?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jtag  

Such a cable will most likely not help you.  Your best bet would be taking the phone to your carrier where they should be able to SIM-unlock it for you.

Comment: I don't know about the jacket. I asked a cell services provider if I can get the unlock code. He told me that I if 2 options for unlocking the sim either through code or using a jacket to unclock it. That's is my question if there is something like unlocking the phone using a jacket for the sim card

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix things here. From your posts it looks like you have entered your SIMs PIN to often and need now to enter your [PUC/PUK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_unblocking_code). This has nothing do to with your androids phone lock. In Germany it's common practice to receive the PUK together with the SIM card. If you have no PUK you can only ask your SIM provider for the PUK or a new SIM. I am not aware of any other method to unblock a blocked SIM.

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood your operator.  There is no such thing as *jacket* for the phone. Either you misinterpreted the support guy, or he is just incompetent person.

If you have locked your phone you have two options:

- Official phone manufacturer representative can help you with resetting the phone to the factory state.
- If you don't want to mess with official support (sometimes it's a waste of time), you can try to unlock your phone manually using just usb cable and commercial software tool ([DaVinci](http://davinciteam.eu/), for example - I've used they service couple of times). If this will fail you can always fall back to the option one. Please note, however - trying to unlock your phone manually you can lose your warranty.